How to add LWC Global action in FSL
I wanted to add a global action in FSL app from where LWC will be called. I used this solution
LWC Global action using Aura component
wherein I called my LWC from aura, but it is not visible in FSL app. I have added action in global publish layout. I have provided 'Access Lightning Web Component in FSL' permission also.
I used this official youtube video as reference. But, it is not working. Global action is visible in Salesforce Web application but not in FSL android app.

Actually, it is visible on FSL app once LWC is called directly, but calling LWC from Aura will not work on FSL. Since aura is not supported on FSL (it is not written anywhere in the salesforce documentation).Call LWC directly from global action and add it in publisher layout.
Use this xml file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="yourComponentname">
    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__GlobalAction</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
 <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__GlobalAction">
         <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
       </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

